# Problems with simplexlxs

Tags: php, excel, pdo

I have a code with simplexlsx but when i upload the .xlsx file, this insert the file twice in my mysql database, and i was trying to delete all the rows in my database before the new file insert but this isn't happening, how can i avoid that?

```
 if (isset($_FILES['file'])) {

 require_once __DIR__ . '/simplexlsx.class.php';

 if ( $xlsx = SimpleXLSX::parse( $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'] ) ) {
  $st = $conn->prepare( "DELETE FROM procura");
  $stmt = $conn->prepare( "INSERT INTO paises (item, codigo_sap, descripcion, und, menor_precio, peso, volumen, provmenor, paisprov, nproceso, emprescon, econtra, fecha) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
  $stmt->bindParam( 1, $item);
  $stmt->bindParam( 2, $codsap);
  $stmt->bindParam( 3, $desc);
  $stmt->bindParam( 4, $und);
  $stmt->bindParam( 5, $menor);
  $stmt->bindParam( 6, $peso);
  $stmt->bindParam( 7, $volumen);
  $stmt->bindParam( 8, $provme);
  $stmt->bindParam( 9, $provpis);
  $stmt->bindParam( 10, $proceso);
  $stmt->bindParam( 11, $econcur);
  $stmt->bindParam( 12, $econtr);
  $stmt->bindParam( 13, $fecha);
    foreach ( $xlsx->rows() as $fields ) {
        if($fields== 1){ $fields++; continue; }
        $item = $fields[0];
        $codsap = $fields[1];
        $desc = $fields[2];
        $und = $fields[3];
        $menor = $fields[4];
        $peso = $fields[5];
        $volumen = $fields[6];
        $provme = $fields[7];
        $provpis = $fields[8];
        $proceso = $fields[9];
        $econcur = $fields[10];
        $econtr = $fields[11];
        $fecha = $fields[12];
        $stmt->execute();

    }

} else {
    echo SimpleXLSX::parse_error();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're preparing the statement `$st`:

```
$st = $conn->prepare( "DELETE FROM procura");
```

But never executing it. You either need to call [`execute()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.execute.php) on the statement handle:

```
$st = $conn->prepare( "DELETE FROM procura");
$st->execute();
```

Or because you are only using the statement once and there is no benefit to preparing, you can just use [`query()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/pdo.query.php):

```
$conn->query("DELETE FROM procura");
```